# Can I encrypt an external harddisk which is in HFS+?

Tags: macos, encryption

***(journaled, encrypted)*** is a new option which I am able to find in Lion.

Can I convert an existing harddrive (external) to encrypt the whole drive instead of using other tools ?

Comment: Similar question answered in another discussion.

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19918/how-to-create-an-encrypted-volume-on-an-external-drive-or-flash-drive/19920#19920

Comment: This question is to do it w/o **formatting** the disk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whole disks, no, but partitions, yes. While the Disk Utility GUI application cannot, the `diskutil` command-line utility [can do this](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/1935/lions-whole-disk-encryption).

First, come up with a password (such as `myVerySecurePassword`). I believe this is *not* tied to your login password, unlike encrypting the boot volume.

Then, find out the identifier for the target volume, e.g. `disk1s1`:

```
diskutil list
```

Then, use `diskutil cs convert`, like so:

```
diskutil cs convert disk1s1 -passphrase myVerySecurePassword
```

Comment: Within Disk Utility you now have encrypted as an option when you erase a partition, but this won't help if you wish to preserve data and convert a drive in use.  If you are unhappy with command line tools, you can backup your data, format with encryption via Diam Manager, then restore into it.

Comment: For 99.9% of the population, trying to distinguish 'whole disk' vs 'partition' is pointlessly pedantic and confusing.  To take it to the extreme, nothing using off-the-shelf drives is 'whole disk'.

Comment: I had originally left that first sentence out. Given the asker's mentioning of encryption, journaling, Disk Utility, etc., I wouldn't classify him as the average user who may not understand the concepts of having multiple volumes on one disk, so I figured I'd mention it.

Comment: @zzz also note that stackexchange's *primary* target groups are power users, serious hobbyists and professionals, not the three nines of population :-) @Sören great info! I found out it was impossible to create both encrypted and non-encrypted partitions onto the same disk with Disk Utility.app, but with `diskutil` it was possible. NB: just *having* an encrypted partition on a disk disables the partition tools of the graphical Disk Utility for the disk.

Comment: Thanks to Apple this command will not work anymore. The only way now to create a HFS+ encrypted disk is to format the disk using Catalina or other older version of macOS. By mere luck, I have an old Mac here, did just this and the disk is working fine under Monterey.