# FileVault (CoreStorage) + Linux partition

Tags: macbook-pro, encryption, unix, filevault, core-storage

Quick question here. I'm not really familiar with the requirements of CoreStorage so I'd like to confirm with you guys before I start working.

I'm currently running OSX Lion on my MacBook Air, with the SSD encrypted with FileVault. I'd like to partition 10GB in order to install Linux (Ubuntu) on it.

However, due to the nature of FileVault (CoreStorage), I cannot touch the partitions without removing encryption.

If I decrypt/remove FileVault, partition with Disk Utility, and encrypt/reapply FileVault on my Lion partition, will there be problems/will this work?

Comment: The first half of your question is clear. Turn off encryption and once the machine is done re-writing everything, you will be free to have multiple partitions work with other OS. The second half is more problematic. It's not clear you can re-encrypt part of the drive. Is that what you hope to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry, was just hoping to reencrypt the Lion partition using FileVault (which uses the CoreStorage structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at this StackExchange thread and the linked articles contained: [Is File Vault 2 whole disk encryption or whole partition encryption?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19226/is-file-vault-2-whole-disk-encryption-or-whole-partition-encryption)

Assuming what you are aiming for is an encrypted Lion partition and an unencrypted Linux partition, the decrypt, partition, encrypt process described will accomplish what you are looking for.

As always, back up first.